# Usage of #ifndef directive

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to use #ifndef as below.

```
#ifndef MACRO1 || #ifndef MACRO2
....
#endif
```

I already tried:

```
#ifndef (MACRO1 || MACRO2) 
..
#endif
```

But for both cases  am getting below error

> error: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are special abbreviations for `#if defined(...)` and `#if !defined(...)`. However, they can only be used for a single macro and do not allow for logical operations. So, if checking for multiple macros, use `#if` with the `defined()` operator instead. Being a regular operatior, this can be combined with logical operations, as the for `!defined()` already does.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `#if` preprocessor directive instead:

```
#if !defined(MACRO1) || !defined(MACRO2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
#if !defined(MACRO1) || !defined(MACRO2)
#endif
```

> You can use the defined operator in the #if directive to use
>   expressions that evaluate to 0 or 1 within a preprocessor line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical operators in preprocessor directives, but in order to check something defined, use the `defined` directive:

```
#if !defined MACRO1 || !defined MACRO2
....
#endif
```